# java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://start.spring.io

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-tool-suite

I am trying to create a Spring Starter Project in STS installed in Eclipse, however the IDE throws an error as the question title.

Below is the complete exception stack trace:

```
java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: http://start.spring.io
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.gettingstarted.boot.NewSpringBootWizardModel.parseJsonFrom(NewSpringBootWizardModel.java:477)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.gettingstarted.boot.NewSpringBootWizardModel.discoverOptions(NewSpringBootWizardModel.java:371)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.gettingstarted.boot.NewSpringBootWizardModel.<init>(NewSpringBootWizardModel.java:150)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.gettingstarted.boot.NewSpringBootWizardModel.<init>(NewSpringBootWizardModel.java:137)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.gettingstarted.boot.NewSpringBootWizardModel.<init>(NewSpringBootWizardModel.java:132)
    at org.springframework.ide.eclipse.wizard.gettingstarted.boot.NewSpringBootWizard.init(NewSpringBootWizard.java:65)
    at org.eclipse.ui.internal.dialogs.WorkbenchWizardNode.getWizard(WorkbenchWizardNode.java:176)
......
```

Here is the Platform details:

```
eclipse.buildId=4.5.1.M20150904-0015
java.version=1.8.0_66
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86_64, WS=win32, NL=en_IN
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
Command-line arguments:  -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
```

I am able to ping `start.spring.io`, any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That is a forbidden error. They are probably blocking your `User-Agent` header from making network requests to the page. You could try changing that.

Comment: Cricket may be on to something with the 'user-agent'. We've had issues with that in the past. STS is setting user agent explicitly to identify itself as a specific version of STS. If you are behind a corporate firewall it is possible that some rules have been defined there to only allow specific user-agents through, for example to limit to known/specific web browsers. So this is a possible explanation if you are behind a corporate firewall.

Comment: Did you solve this ?

Answer (score 2):

At last, I navigated to http://start.spring.io/ & then generated my project from there